# Do I need to use a broadcast variable when using variable in foreachRDD?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka

In my code, I subscribe to a Kafka stream and process each RDD in a function:

```
  val myStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[K, V](
      streamingContext,
      PreferConsistent,
      Subscribe[K, V](topics, consumerConfig)
    )

  val myMap: Map[ObjA, ObjB] = getMyMap() // This is the variable I want to access in 'process'

  def process(record: (RDD[ConsumerRecord[String, String]], Time)): Unit = record match {

     // Code that uses myMap.get("key")

  }

  myStream.foreachRDD((x, y) => process((x, y)))
```

I read this post about [Spark and Kafka integration patterns](https://allegro.tech/2015/08/spark-kafka-integration.html). As far as I understood, `foreachRDD` is executed locally on the driver, but then any inner loops are distributed to cluster nodes. Does that mean that I *should* [broadcast](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-broadcast.html) `myMap` for performance reasons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does that mean that I should broadcast myMap for performance reasons?

Well:

- If you don't [*The data broadcasted this way is cached in serialized form and deserialized before running each task*](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables).
- If you do, Spark will keep a copy on each executor, and reuse when needed.

Because variable is reused across multiple tasks, there is a value in broadcasting, especially if data is large enough to add significant overhead.

If not, it might be preferebale to stick with closure serialization for better readability (I acknowledge this is a matter of preference).

Answer (score 1):

> but then any inner loops are distributed to cluster nodes

It isn't "any inner loops" which are distributed, but operations on RDD.

So it depends on how exactly `myMap.get("key")` is used inside `process`. E.g. here is an example where broadcasting is completely pointless:

```
def process(record: (RDD[ConsumerRecord[String, String]], Time)): Unit = record match {
  case (rdd, _) => rdd.take(10).filter(/* do something using myMap */)
}
```